# MySQLConnection throws an Exception in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

I don't know what is happening to my `MySql.Data` why it is always encountering an error when I am opening a connection.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection();
myconn.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.0.xxx;port=3306;database=db_name;user id=root;password=pass123";
if (myconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     myconn.Open();
```

then after `myconn.Open();` is reach.

[image]

I am searching for that specific error here in stack but I don't see any answer.

**PS:**  The code of `MySqlConnection` is working fine yesterday, but I don't know why that error appear a little while ago.

**PPS :** I tried the code of `MySqlConnection` in different projects and It is working fine too, but When it comes to my real project it is not working.

Comment: Have you granted the privileges ? GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.0.%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'some_characters'  
WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Comment: please put error you heve got

Comment: Have you enable SQL Server Debugging.May be this resolve his issue. also try to post stack trace with your connection code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately, I have some modifications to my project

like:

- adding and removing some **Application Settings**
- Changing the .Net Framework version from 4.0 to 4.6.1 vice versa.

after of that many modification when the errors occurred.
and I think because of that, the `MySqlConnection` was affected and not working.

Now I don't know why or how, but I solve my problem by changing the Assembly Information from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.1.0.
Changing the Assembly Information will [cause the compiler to reevaluate the configuration and cause the application to refrain from creating and reading a new user.config file corresponding to the new version due to there being no user settings in the new version.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18610005/5693082)