# How to make an NUnit TestProject use its own config when run?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Is it possible to let Resharper (or NUnit?) know that I want each test to look for an `App.config` under it's own project, even when running all tests in a solution together?

**Background:**

I'm using NUnit and the test-runner that ships with Resharper, and I've got several test-projects in the same solution. Some of my tests depend on config-files located under their respective projects.

When I run a test-project by itself, it will use it's internal `App.config`, and everything works fine. When I try to run all the tests in the solution, or use the shortcut to `run all tests in current test session` however, no config-file will be selected, and any test depending on a config will fail by default.

For this reason, I typically end up running all tests in the solution once first, then right clicking the nodes in the test-runner for each of the config-dependent projects, and running them separately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Apparently assemblies containing NUnit-tests [can be run in separate processes or domains using command line options](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assemblyIsolation&r=2.5.5).

For the testrunner under Resharper, this setting can be found under `Resharper > Options > Unit Testing`.

There is an option "*Use separate AppDomain for each assempbly with tests*".  Checking that solved my problem.

[image]