# Implementation of Unit test and acceptance test in a .NET project

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, nunit, integration-testing

I've read [this article](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) and a couple of others about testing and I think I've understand the theory but not the implementation in a real .NET project.

My project is decomposed in multiple (functional) assemblies and I wish to test it. Most of my methods and properties are private or internal so I can't access them from my test assembly.
I only test the public one (in order to test all the paths of my assembly).

I'm wondering about the test I'm doing because these tests aren't unit-test because I'm using other services like a database, or other services like Microsoft HPC... Am I right ? In my opinion, if I want to do some unit test, I have to test private methods and properties, thing that is controversial.

I'm using Nunit and I was wondering if I could put integration test AND unit test in the framework ?

Is there any .NET opensource project with unit test and acceptance test that I could check out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions...

**public/private**: Typically, you only want to test through the public interface. If you want to test a private method it's probably a sign of that you should split the class into two and let the private methods become public (or internal). SRP. To test internal method, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358196/c-sharp-internal-access-modifier-when-doing-unit-testing/1809482#1809482).

When writing a test you want to test the behaviour of the system. With behaviour, think of how the system behaves as seen from the end user (although there could be other interesting stakeholders as well). If you do this, you seldom encounter the problem with wanting to test private methods.

The difference between a **unit test** and an **integration test** is debated and, in my opinion, not a very important debate. What's more important is to ask yourself, what's the purpose of the test?

If your purpose is to test your system (as opposed to e.g. the integration with external systems), your tests should be repeatable, fast and not include anything you don't own. With repeatable I mean that, if the test fails once it should fail always (no randomness). With fast I mean that you should not have to wait too long for the feedback from running all your tests. With what you own I mean that the tests should not start failing due to changes made outside your organisation. If you can achieve this and still include calls to the database and/or Microsoft HPC, then I don't see any reason why not.

To differerentiate between different test types in **NUnit** you can use [categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.6.1). Most tools allow you to run a subset based on these.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have to intervene on Torbjörns answer.

There is a BIG difference between unit test and integration test, which can't be handled with categories only. Just think about all the references or dependencies, which are needed in an integration test. Who ever tried to run integration tests on a build machine can tell you the story.

**Rule of thumb:** NEVER mix up unit tests and integration tests. 
You can reuse the same test runner, like NUnit, but you have to split the test projects.

P.S.: welcome to the TDD journey!