# Is it possible for methods to have dual access modifiers?

Tags: c#, internal, access-modifiers, test-framework, test-project

I have many methods that are defined internal like so:

```
internal static string GetAJobShaNaNaNaShaNaNaNaNaNa(string Silhouettes)
```

However, in order to call them from a test project added to the solution, I need to change their access modifier from internal to public.

Is there a non-tedious way to make these methods public to the tests, yet remain internal otherwise?

Comment: Just ran out of close votes, so I'll leave this here for someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358196/c-sharp-internal-access-modifier-when-doing-unit-testing

Comment: If you truly need to test internal methods, and not just their public interfaces, then you can use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not add [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in your assembly to allow the tests access?

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembly")]
```

Comment: Just to be clear for others, this needs to be added to the \Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file

Answer (score 1):

You can use internalsvisibletoattribute.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx