# For unit testing how to make a namespace derived?

Tags: c#, namespaces, access-modifiers

I have two namespaces:

```
namespace MyNamespace
```

and

```
namespace MyNamespace.Test
```

the second one is for Unit Testing. I don't want to make the classes within "MyNamespace" public but I want the unit tests to be able to access them. I tried internal because from the [Access Modifier documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) I had assumed that "MyNamespace.test" would be derived but it's not working. Do I use a different access modifier or is my namespace wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces have no bearing on accessibility / visibility in C#; they are simply prefixes to type names to enable grouping of similar types together, for use with things like `using` statements. It's essentially a compile-time concept, the runtime doesn't recognize namespaces as logical entities and requires fully-qualified names in the compiled code.

Instead, access is done on a per-assembly basis. An assembly is the `.dll` or `.exe` file each C# project produces. The same namespace may appear in multiple assemblies, and multiple namespaces may appear in the same assembly.

Marking something `internal` means "allow access to it from anywhere in the same assembly as where this thing is declared". So if your unit tests are in a different assembly (as they should be, unless you want to ship your unit tests to customers!), they won't be able to access types in the `MyNamespace`, regardless of what namespace the tests are declared in.

However, you can have your product assemblies allow an exception to this rule with the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358196/c-sharp-internal-access-modifier-when-doing-unit-testing).