# UTA001: TestClass attribute defined on non-public class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to run the test from the internal class and I am getting error:

> UTA001: TestClass attribute defined on non-public class

How can I run tests of internal classes using VS and vstest.console.exe?

EDIT: Here is my class and test:

```
[TestClass]
internal class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string test = "Test Test";
        var res = test is IEnumerable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# "internal" access modifier when doing unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358196/c-sharp-internal-access-modifier-when-doing-unit-testing)

Comment: @jtabuloc My internal class is located in my test project. It couldn't help

Comment: Why you don't want the test class to be public?

Comment: You can use NUnit framework. `TestFixture` attribute of NUnit can be used with `internal` test class

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to your Test Assembly:

```
[assembly: DiscoverInternals]
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/main/src/TestFramework/TestFramework/Attributes/Lifecycle/Initialization/DiscoverInternalsAttribute.cs).