# Ways to make classes unit testable having dependency on resources

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resources

I have a class which is dependent on a resource string. It accesses, for example, a resource string as `var str = Resources.INCORRECT_PASSWORD;`. What is the correct way to use resources so that the class becomes unit testable?

Comment: Where is the resource file located in relation to the consuming class? Same project, same solution, different solution?

Comment: If you dont want to make the resource file public you mark the assemibly as InternalVisibleTo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106907/making-code-internal-but-available-for-unit-testing-from-other-projects

Comment: @ChrisBint It is in the same project.